# Cannot login to MediaWiki-API with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, mediawiki, file-get-contents

Where did I make a mistake? My PHP-script:

```
<?php
// Set username and password
$lgname = "someUsername";
$lgpassword = "somePassword";

// First login to receive 1) token, 2) sessionid and 3) cookieprefix
$parameters = array('action' => 'login', 'lgname' => "$lgname", 'lgpassword' => "$lgpassword", 'format' => 'json');
options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($parameters)
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", false, $context);

// Echo out the answer from MediaWiki-API
echo "$result";

// Put the needed parts of the answer into variables and echo them out
$array = json_decode($result,true);
$token = $array["login"]["token"];
$sessionid = $array["login"]["sessionid"];
$cookieprefix = $array["login"]["cookieprefix"];
echo "</BR>token: $token, sessionid: $sessionid, cookieprefix: $cookieprefix</BR>";

// Second login to 1) post token and 2) send sessionID within the header
$parameters = array('action' => 'login', 'lgname' => "$lgname", 'lgpassword' => "$lgpassword", 'lgtoken' => "$token", 'format' => 'json');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
             "Cookie: " . $cookieprefix . "_session = $sessionid\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($parameters)
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", false, $context);

// Echo out result
echo "$result";
?>
```

What I get as an answer to my second POST-request is (exactly the same as to my first POST-request) that I need a token (even though I posted the token and even the sessionID in my second POST-request):

```
{"login": {
    "result":"NeedToken",
    "token":"82b3f2e1f1aa702ca6ceae473bb16bde",
    "cookieprefix":"dewiki",
    "sessionid":"531143bd7425722bf1be88e520dea6d5"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in using `file_get_contents()` in the first place. Use a [PHP library for the MediaWiki web API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#PHP), instead.

If you really want to do things yourself, [ask a token from meta=tokens](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tokens).